# Delete old log files with OnStartupTriggeringPolicy and DirectWriteRolloverStrategy

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j-slf4j-impl version 2.12.1.
And an application that will be executed via command line and ternimated after finished.

The application won't be executed more than once at the same time in local host, but it's possible we run it again while previous application is running.
So I'd like to separate logging files by yyyyMMdd-HHmmss, then delete ones if file modified time is elder than specified age (here I set as 1 minute for testing) when application startup.

My log4j2.xml content:

```xml
<RollingFile name="default"
             filePattern="${output.folder}/my.%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0" />
    </Policies>

    <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${output.folder}" maxDepth="1">
            <IfFileName glob="my*.log" />
            <IfLastModified age="1m" />
        </Delete>
    </DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
```

logging files are look like below:

- my.20191127-091410.log
- my.20191127-091415.log
- my.20191127-091527.log
- my.20191127-091533.log

The question is above log4j2 setting is not working.
Old logging files are not deleted.
Is there something wrong in my log4j2 setting?

I'm very appreciated for any comments.

--- 20191203T160657+0800 ---

I replaced  to  in log4j2.xml as below per @metters suggestion:

```xml
<RollingFile name="default"
             filePattern="${output.folder}/my.%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
    </Policies>

    <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${output.folder}" maxDepth="1">
            <IfFileName glob="my*.log" />
            <IfLastModified age="1m" />
        </Delete>
    </DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
```

And my test application is

```java
public class Library {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("Hi");
        for(int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++)
        {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            log.info("{}", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Old files are deleted correctly, but new log file will be created per second.
According my test application, there are 6 files are created:

- my.20191203-160338.log contains "Hi".
- my.20191203-160339.log contains "0".
- my.20191203-160340.log contains "1".
- my.20191203-160341.log contains "2".
- my.20191203-160342.log contains "3".
- my.20191203-160343.log contains "4".

Log4j2 is rolling file by second. Log messages should be written to my.20191203-160338.log.

I tried to trace code and found something weird.

First, the outputstream (shown as below) will be null because no fileName attribute while using DirectWriteRolloverStrategy:
[image: outputstream is null in RollingFileManager]

Second, RollingFileManager doesn't nothing in its own rollover method due to OutputStream is null and hence there is no chance to do rollover of DirectWriteRolloverStrategy (shown as below):
[image: no rollover due to outputstream is null]

Do I understand in wrong way?

Please let me know if I do something wrong or any suggestion.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this locally (not running in parallel) and managed to delete log files older than one minute by changing the `<OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0" />` to `<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />`

With that configuration a new file was created every second (My program called log.info() every second one time in an infinite loop).

After one minute the oldest files were deleted, I never had more than 61 files in my folder.
Just adapt the configuration to your needs (one file per minute etc) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, but one file per minute doesn't meet my requirement, because more than one application could be executed within one minute. Each running application must write logs to its own file. Let me know if any ideas, thank you.

Comment: The solution was not meant to be "one file per minute".
My solution was meant to trigger the deletion of the old files, as requested. Please adapt the configuration like i wrote in my answer and test whether the files get deleted or not.

Comment: Hi, I updated my post, please take a look for the result. Thank you.